# glutPassiveMotionFunc() seems to be called at the start of movement not at the end. How do I call it again at the end?

Tags: python, opengl, glut

I am relatively new to OpenGL programming, and I am having some trouble keeping the mouse in the center. From what I can see, glutPassiveMotionFunc() is called when the mouse starts moving, and not at the end of movement, because in the function, I set the mouse position back to the center:

```
def on_mouse_move(x, y):
     xpos = glut.glutGet(glut.GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH) / 2
     ypos = glut.glutGet(glut.GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT) / 2
     glut.glutWarpPointer(xpos, ypos)


glut.glutPassiveMotionFunc(on_mouse_move)
glut.glutMotionFunc(on_mouse_move)
```

but the cursor only moves back to the center whenever I start moving it again. If I stop moving the mouse, the cursor stays at the position that it last was, and then when I start moving it again, it moves it back to the center.

How can I call the function at the end of the movement, or at least call it one extra time once movement has stopped to reset it?